# How do I get Attributes out of an empty XML Element?

Tags: java, xml

I am new to Java and XML and I am trying to get Attributes out of an empty Element.
Could you guys help me out?

I did try things like node.getTextContent() and stuff like that but it just wont work...

This is what the empty Elements in a Node look like...

```xml
<AnimalRe AnimalID='A.01' OrderNumber='1'/>
<AnimalRe AnimalID='A.02' OrderNumber='2'/>
<AnimalRe AnimalID='A.03' OrderNumber='3'/>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please could you post a [mcve] showing what you've tried? Aside from anything else, there are lots of different XML APIs you might be using - we'll need to know which API in order to help you.

Comment: If you're using the `org.w3c.dom` API, are you looking for [`Node.getAttributes()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.xml/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#getAttributes())?

Comment: When I try to print out the Node.getAttributes() it gives me sth. like this: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.AttributeMap@91161c7

Comment: And yes I am using the org.w3c.dom API

Comment: I also tried to cast the AnimalRe Nodes to an Element and print out the Attribute AnimalID with element.getAttribute("AnimalID"); this gives me a java.lang.ClassCastException

Comment: The `getAttributes()` method, as shown in the documentation I linked, returns a `NamedNodeMap`—you have to use its API. And what is the message of the `ClassCastException` ([edit] your question to add information)?  Also, if you want me to be aware of your comments, please [ping me](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work).